# Pandoc: complete pass through from tex to html?

Tags: pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert *TeX* files into *HTML* files (to be used with JeKyll).

I want to insert some *raw block* directly into the *TeX* file in a way that it survives, without any alteration, the conversion from *TeX* to *HTML*.

For instance, I might want to add something like this:

```
{% highlight python %}
def func(ok):
    return ok
{% endhighlight %}
```

I can do this from *md* to *HTML* by using `{=html}`, but what about the *TeX->md* part?

Comment: I guess you could write a pandoc filter to automate this... but I'd recommend converting TeX to markdown once, then fixing up your markdown, then using `jekyll` or `jekyll-pandoc` to generate the HTML...

Comment: @mb21 OK, but in the tex->md conversion I lose the raw block. That's the main problem. Do I need a pandoc filter or is there an easier way?

Comment: you have raw HTML in your LaTeX? I don't understand... that wouldn't compile with a latex engine...

Comment: I use LyX because it's very handy. I can insert raw LaTeX from LyX so I'll use that.
I export the document as plain TeX and then use pandoc for the conversion to HTML.
I want some raw jekyll-specific code to pass through the whole process.

Comment: you'll have to show us a snippet of the LaTeX you export from Lyx...

Comment: It's just normal tex. Nothing fancy. You can assume I can insert whatever I want in the tex file. Even better, ignore LyX. Assume I write tex by hand.

Comment: okay, then go with @tarleb's solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires the use of a filter, as @mb21 pointed out alreday.

You'll probably want the input document to remain valid LaTeX, so a good method would be to use a specially marked *verbatim* environment, like so:

```
\begin{verbatim}
%%%HTML
<aside>Embedding raw HTML can be helpful</aside>
\end{verbatim}
```

Pandoc will read this as a normal code block, but we can use a filter to convert it into a raw HTML block:

```
function CodeBlock(cb)
  local rawHtml = cb.text:match('^%s*%%%%%%HTML\n(.*)')
  if rawHtml then
    return pandoc.RawBlock('html', rawHtml)
  end
end
```

Save the above into a file and use it as the argument of pandoc's `--lua-filter` option.

Comment: I see no reference to `verbatim` in the code. Is there a cleaner way? For instance, I could use `\begin{my_special_block}` and then catch that from lua code?

Comment: I forgot that's not valid latex... but I can use `\newenvironment`

Comment: One could use the `raw_tex` pandoc extension when parsing latex, this transforms *every* environment and command unknown to pandoc into a raw latex block.  You could then use lua to parse the contents of these raw blocks.  This would likely end up much more complex than the above (mis)use of the `verbatim` environment.

Comment: @Kiuhnm Another (slightly cleaner) solution would be to use the `minted` package `\begin{minted}{html}…\end{minted}`.  The lua filter function would then become `function CodeBlock (cb) if cb.classes[1] == 'html' then return pandoc.RawBlock('html', cb.text) end end`.  The downside is that one needs to enable shell-escape to compile it as latex.

Comment: Nevermind. Not knowing pandoc well, I didn't realize that verbatim is converted into a codeblock and that you're only inspecting code blocks with that lua code (although the names were quite telling :) ).